# AngularJS: How to clear HTML form from AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope

I want to clear form after completed some actions with user's input. I know how to do this from the controller. For example, I can run following function:

```
$scope.clearForm = function () {
     $scope.addOrEditForm.$setPristine();
     $scope.firstName = "";
     $scope.secondName = "";
     $scope.position = "";
};
```

This works. But I need to call this function from another function, which is located in AngularJS service. How I can call it from there? Or how I can define `clearForm` function in the service and get access to all these form variables like `$scope.firstName`, `$scope.secondName`, `$scope.position`? Thanks for helping!

Comment: pass the $scope as parameter to the service and clear it from there ? you might want to have all those properties (firstname, secondName.. )into one object in the scope, and then pass only that object  to your service, rather than all the $scope

Comment: I would think the best way to do this is create a service function, which then can be used both in the service and the controller, then you can pass all the variables you need from the controller to the service. Or as Gonzalo suggestd, pass the $scope. I just find mixing $scopes causes a lot of issues.

Comment: And how can I pass variables to the service?

Comment: For example I have `proposeNewsCtrl` Controller and `postNewsFactory` Service. `angular.module('twitterApiApp').factory('postNewsFactory', ['$http', 'publicationsFactory', 'channelsFactory',
                                                      function($http, publicationsFactory, channelsFactory) {}` How to inject these variables or 1 object with variables from the controller to the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an event in the controller

```
// listen for the event in the relevant $scope
$scope.$on('myCustomEvent', function (event) {
    $scope.clearForm();
});
```

Call the event from the service

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myCustomEvent');
```